# Is it possible to identify a worm being carried by a depicted wasp?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

Wikimedia has [a picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0e/01-iwes-07-003.jpg) of a [*Ancistrocerus trifasciatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancistrocerus_trifasciatus) / mason wasp carrying a kind of worm:

[image: Ancistrocerus trifasciatus]

Is it possible to tell what exactly kind of worm it is, based only on the above image, number of worm's segments, dots on its skin and a correlation in size to wasp's size (or its feeding preferences)?

I am not the author of the picture, I was not present when it was captures, so I can't provide any more details that are usually helpful in species identification (like moment of day and year, geographic location etc.). The [image itself](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plik:01-iwes-07-003.jpg) doesn't contain any geolocation data, but from its German description in can be assumed that this was captured somewhere in Germany, Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too sure but by the general look of it, it seems to be the leaf beetle **Chrysomela populi**.
This is mostly from the idea that they are very common in Europe and the distribution of the spots on its body. If nothing else it is most likely from the Chrysomela genus.

Here is a link to a description of the [species](https://arthropodafotos.de/dbsp.php?lang=eng&sc=1&ta=t_35_coleo_pol_chr&sci=Chrysomela&scisp=populi)

Comment: For species ID questions, we ask that answerers provide a reference for their ID, and preferably a description of what led them to that ID or defining characteristics (such as things that allow you to exclude other possibilities).